# Spyder IDE/GUI on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, installation, spyder, raspberry-pi4

I am very new to all this, well revisiting. I am thinking about picking up a Rasberry Pi 4 to start learning and practicing my coding. I have limited funds and only have an iPad provided by work. Anyway, before I buy a machine I want to know if Spyder IDE can be installed and used on Raspberry Pi 4. The website was unclear, and as I understand only 32-bit items can be installed or run on Rasp. 4, and Spyder is listed at 64-bit. Any help is appreciated before I buy this machine. Feel free to also recommend other machines to start learning to code on. 
Thank you!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi 3 and 4 have 64 bit CPUs. But to run 64 bit software you will need a 64 bit OS and you will need the right build of Spyder.

Comment: Thank you! Any tips on a good OS that I could use?